# Java using streams as sort of "buffers"

Tags: java, stream

I'm working with a library that I have to provide an InputStream and a PrintStream. It uses the InputStream to gather data for processing and the PrintStream to provide results. I'm stuck using this library and its API cannot be altered.

There are two issues with this that I think have related solutions.

First, the data that needs to be read via the InputStream is not available upfront. Instead, the data is dynamically created by a different part of the application and given to my code as a String via method call. My code's job is to somehow allow the library to read this data through the InputStream provided as I get it.

Second, I need to somehow get the result that is written to the PrintStream and send it to another part of the application as a String. This needs to happen as immediately after the data is put in to the PrintStream as possible.

What it looks like I need are two stream objects that behave more or less like buffers. I need an InputStream that I can shove data in to whenever I have it and a PrintStream that I can grab it's contents whenever it has some. This seems a little awkward to me, but I'm not sure how else to do it.

I'm wondering if anything already exists that allows this kind of behavior or if there is a different (better) solution that will work in the situation I've described. The only thing I can come up with is to try to implement streams with this behavior, but that can become complicated fast (especially since the InputStream needs to block until data is available).

Any ideas?

**Edit**: To be clear, I'm not writing the library. I'm writing code that is supposed to provide the library with an InputStream to read data from and a PrintStream to write data to.

Comment: What have you tried? A little coding should be all you need to get this up and running. This is no different then standard Socket programming.

Comment: I started implementing InputStream and OutputStream to have buffers, but I got stuck on how to properly block when data wasn't available in the InputStream buffer. Also, the application is threaded, so synchronization became an issue and I got lost in how to make sure I block the correct threads in the correct cases and how to wake them up again when the data is available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both streams need to be constantly reading/writing so you'll need two threads independent of each other. The pattern resembles JMS a little bit, in which case you're feeding information to a "queue" or "topic", and wait for it to be processed then put on a "output" queue/topic. This may introduce additional moving parts, but you could write a simple client to place info onto a JMS queue, then have a listener to just grab messages, and feed it to the input stream constantly. Then another piece of code to read from output stream, and do what you need with it. 
Hope this helps.